# Write {1,...,3n} as the disjoint union of arithmetic progressions of length 3 and steps 1, 2,...,n

Tags: co.combinatorics, arithmetic-progression

For $n \equiv 0, 1, 2 \pmod 9$, write $\{\,1,\dots,3n\,\}$ as the disjoint union of arithmetic progressions $A_1, A_2,\dots,A_n$ of length 3, where $A_i$ has step $i$.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61744 to get an idea of a solution.  This is the wrong forum for your question.  Gerhard "Trying Small Examples Helps Much" Paseman, 2017.04.26.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the right forum or not, but I would like to know the source of this question, and what you have found in your own efforts to solve it, William.

Comment: Wait, so how does this work for $n=2$?

Comment: @René, for small values of $n$, there are certainly no solutions. E.g., for $n=3$, $A_1$ and $A_3$ can't be disjoint. It's not immediately clear to me what happens when $n$ is large. (Although I realize $n=3$ doesn't satisfy the congruence modulo 9, but it's also not clear to me why one wants to impose that condition.)

Comment: Look up Langford sequences/triples. There is a variation where step size is i+1 instead of i. One of them has solutions with those values of n, and there may be a proof that those values are necessary.  Gerhard "Doesn't Know The Proof Yet" Paseman, 2017.04.26.

Comment: I tried it for some small values (small but bigger than 2) and it is possible to do this for n = 9, 10, 11, 18, 19. 20.

For 10, for example, the following works:

(1, 2, 3)
(4, 6, 8)
(7, 10, 13)
(20, 24, 28)
(11, 16, 21)
(17, 23, 29)
(12, 19, 26)
(14, 22, 30)
(9, 18, 27)
(5, 15, 25)

Comment: Curiously, it appears not to work for numbers that do not satisfy your assumption, suggesting you may have some obstruction for those...care to share? :)