# Covering a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with prime arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-progression, covering

Because of a problem I ran into I am trying to get a quick start in covering with arithmetic progressions.

First I want to say I am aware of this previously asked question:
[Covering $\mathbb{N}$ with prime arithmetic progressions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80494/covering-mathbbn-with-prime-arithmetic-progressions)

Similarly to what is asked there I am interested in covering with arithmetic progressions of the type $A_{i}=k_{i}+np_{i}$ where $p_{i}$ is prime, $k_{i} \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N_{0}}$.

Differently, my interests are however in covering of finite sets of the type $\{1, 2, \ldots, N\} \subset \mathbb{N}$ where $k_{i}<p_{i}$ and $p_{1} \leq p_{i} \leq p_{m}$.

By checking out some numbers it looks like that if all $k_{i}=p_{i}-1$ the covered set is $\{1, 2, \ldots, p_{m+1}-2 \}$.

So my questions are:

Let $p_{1} \leq p_{i} \leq p_{m}$ be the first $m$ consecutive primes and $\forall p_{i}$ let $A_{i}=k_{i}+np_{i}$ be $m$ arithmetic progressions, where $n \in \mathbb{N_{0}}$ and $k_{i} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1 \leq k_{i}<p_{i}$. Obviously is the arithmetic progression $A_{1}=k_{1}+np_{1}=1+2n$ fixed and covers all the odd numbers in all considerations.

1. If $\forall p_{i}$ with $k_{i}=p_{i}-1$ is the covered set always $\{1, 2, \ldots, p_{m+1}-2 \}$, that is are all numbers up to $N=p_{m+1}-2$ covered?
2. Will all sets of $k_{i}$ values where one or more $k_{i}<p_{i}-1$ give less coverage?
3. (If "no" to 2.) Is there any set of $k_{i}$ values where one or more $k_{i}<p_{i}-1$ gives more coverage, that is covers numbers up to $N>p_{m+1}-2$?

Additional questions/help.
I would appreciate all relevant information possible, like: Has this been proved?, Then by whom?; Any textbooks discussing this or very similar kind of problems; Websites; etc.

Comment: I'd suggest to make this question self-contained (while it should mention the respective previous *OM Question*, let your new question explain each term independently, to avoid any confusion).

Comment: You wrote: *I am interesting*. It is great that you are *interesting* but you can ask way more **SPECIFIC** questions than just claiming than you are interesting (of course I believe that you are).

Comment: Given any $r$, let $p$ be a prime dividing $r+1$, then $r$ is in the arithmetic progression $(p-1)+np$.

Comment: I have updated the question in an attempt to make it more self-contained (and correct grammar). I hope I have understood your suggestions Wlodzimierz. 

Your input Gerry is very helpful, it gives a "quick start" insight.

Thanks to you both.

Comment: Doesn't my comment actually answer your question 1?

Comment: Thank you, @augu. I'd still write that $p_k$ are primes. Are $p_1<p_k<\ldots$ all consecutive primes $2\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 11\ \ldots$? Do you exclude prime $2$ (the earlier MO Question did)? ... Also, may be it's just me, but I  don't understand the formulations of your questions (if it's just me than it's ok, no problem). Those who write questions BOTH in simple words AND using formulas (like $\forall_{x\in X}\exists_{\delta > 0}\ldots$) make me happy :-)

Comment: Q1: Yes.  Q2: no.  Lookup Westzynthius, Jacobsthal, recent work of Tao, Green, Ford, and Kolvagin (announced last month.).

Comment: @Włodzimierz Holsztyński I have refined the text again, even though I thought the first prime was included in previous revision I agree some parts were not as clear enough.  Yes the primes are the first $m$ primes including 2, and one and only one arithmetic progression with each one.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson as I said it was a good "quick start insight" giving me something to think about. Having done that I understand as all numbers up to $p_{m+1}$ are divisible by one or more prime up to $p_{m}$ your suggestion shows that the numbers are covered with this kind of arithmetic progressions.  Thanks again.

Comment: @The Masked Avenger thank you for the suggestions. After taking a quick second look at Tao, Green, Ford and Konyagin I found out that maybe it is near this than I thought, but surely I have to read it few times more.  One question though does your answer "Q2: no." hold after I added the restriction that the arithmetic progressions are exactly one with each prime?

Comment: Your new restriction is not clear.  I have assumed from the outset that you were using m a.p's with m distinct differences, each a prime.

Comment: Yes $m$ distinct consecutive primes and each is a difference in exactly one of the $m$ arithmetic progressions.

Comment: Added the third question because if the answer to 2 is "no" because if the coverage is more than up to $N=p_{m}-2$ it is interesting to know how much more.

Comment: Restating @Gerry Myerson above: Given any $r-1$, let $p$ be a prime dividing $r$, then $r-1$ is in the arithmetic progression $k+np$ with $k=p-1$ which covers up to $N=p_{m}-2$ in the case described above.  

Now extending on that: Given any $r-t$, let $p$ be a prime dividing $r$, then $r-t$ is in the arithmetic progression $k+np$ with $k= (p-t) \bmod p$ which also covers up to $N=p_{m}-2$ if $t$ is odd. Unfortunately this includes some $k=0<1$ so $t=1$ is the only acceptable value of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to studying large intervals of numbers that are not coprime to a product of some
selected prime numbers.  When one has such a large interval, one can translate it by
subtraction to begin at 1, and can compute the requisite k_i.  Taking m to be 5, n the product
of the first m primes, in this case n=2310, we find the interval of nontotients of n from
114  to 126: translating the k's in  increasing order of p_i are 1,1,2,6,8. This tiles 13 integers, and 13 is
greater than 13-2.

Again searching MathOverflow for  Jacobsthal's function should give you more examples

Comment: Aha! Somehow your previous Jacobsthal reference missed my attention.  Not that I understand it immediately, but I have confirmed that your $k$ values $1,1,2,6,8$ give better coverage indeed.
This confirms the answer to question 2. is "no" and 3 is  "yes".
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer.